# Can I use Firebase user authentication in DatabaseReferences?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I have a database working on firebase as well as user authentication, but I cannot figure out how to use the users email or UID as a child reference. I am using user.getEmail() for retrieving their email as a string and then putting that in either a .child() or .getReference(). When doing this it always crashes my app. I believe it is something to do with how I am organizing it but I am not positive. Anyone have any clues?

---

```
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser user;

private TextView mTextView;

private String email;
//private String other;

FirebaseDatabase testReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
DatabaseReference conditionRef=testReference.getReference();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_page);

    mTextView=findViewById(R.id.Condition);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();


    user=mAuth.getCurrentUser();
    if(user!=null){
        mTextView.setText("User on Page!");
        email=user.getEmail();
        conditionRef.child(email);
    }
    if(user==null)
        mTextView.setText("User not on Page");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check out the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security)

There is a clear example

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are trying to send the email to the database, atleast that what I think you are trying to do, try this:

```
if(user!=null){
    mTextView.setText("User on Page!");
    email=user.getEmail();
    conditionRef.child("users").child(user.getUid()).child("email").setValue(email);
}
```

Your Database must look like:

```
users
|
|----userID
     |
      ----"email":"someone@something.com"
```